# Recursively get all Children from a MySQL database

Tags: python, mysql

```
+--------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| Field        | Type         | Null | Key | Default | Extra |
+--------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| subject      | int(11)      | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| relationship | varchar(266) | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| target       | int(11)      | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
+--------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
```

if I have an ID, and I want to get its children, I would run this query:

```
select subject from chebi_obo_relationships where target = %s and relationship="is_a";
```

This would give me all of its children for the relationship 'is_a'. Then I want to find all of those childrens' children. And I want to keep going until there are no more kids. And in the end, I want a list of children IDs that stemmed from my original root ID.

Is there an efficient way to do this? I tried a python script to recursively run that query above, and it takes several minutes to generate ~ 100 results.

Note: A child may have multiple parents

Answer (score 0):

One of the smart ways to store the tree structure in a relational database is to use nested sets.

Suppose, we have the following tree:

```
    1
   / \
  2   3
 /    /\
4    5  6
```

We have a traditional parent_id:

```
| id | parent_id |
|----+-----------|
|  1 | 0         |
|  2 | 1         |
|  3 | 1         |
|  4 | 2         |
|  5 | 3         |
|  6 | 3         |
```

In this model you have no opportunity, but a recursion to get all the descendants of a certain node.

Now we add 2 numbers for each node: left and right.

The left number is less than the numbers of all the node’s children, whereas the right number is greater than the numbers of all the node’s children.

I put these numbers into brackets:

```
    (1)     1        (12)
       /            \
 (2)  2 (5)    (6)   3 (11)
     /           /        \
(3) 4 (4)   (7) 5 (8)  (9) 6 (10)
```

And we get the following table:

```
| id | parent_id | left | right |
|----+-----------+------+-------|
|  1 |         0 |    1 |    12 |
|  2 |         1 |    2 |     5 |
|  3 |         1 |    6 |    11 |
|  4 |         2 |    3 |     4 |
|  5 |         3 |    7 |     8 |
|  6 |         3 |    9 |    10 |
```

Now you can get all the children of a node using 2 queries: at first you get node left and node right, then:

```
SELECT
    id
FROM
    tbl
WHERE
    `left` > $node_left
AND
    `right` < $node_left
```

This approach requires recalculation of left and right when you modify the structure of a tree.

Comment: Are there any Python tools for converting my existing parent->child relation to a nested set model? I can't seem to figure out a way to write this one on my own. Also, a child may have multiple parents. Does this change anything?

Comment: "Also, a child may have multiple parents. Does this change anything?" - yes, unfortunately nested sets model won't work for you. You'll have to figure out your own.

Comment: "Are there any Python tools for converting my existing parent->child relation to a nested set model?" - no, I don't think so. There must be implementations, but you'll have to tweak them.